# upload component in antdesign

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

// I want to use the upload component of antDesing to accept only video files.

```
const beforeUpload = (file) => {
 const isVideo = file.type === 'video/*';  //using (video/*)  is not working here to accept any video file.

        console.log('fle type', file.type);
        if (!isVideo) {
            message.error('You can only upload video file!');
        }

        const isLt10M = file.size / 1024 / 1024 < 10;

        if (!isLt10M) {
            message.error('Video must smaller than 10MB!');
        }

        return isVideo && isLt10M;
    };

    const handleChange = (info) => {
        console.log('info', info);
    };


render(
  <Upload beforeUpload={beforeUpload} onChange={handleChange}>
  <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Click to Upload</Button>
  </Upload>
```

)

//let me know if there is any way to sort the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try it with regex:

```
const regex = /video\/.*/g;
const isVideo = regex.test(file.type);
```